# Keeping a few Linux machines at the same patch level

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, updates

Is there some simple and straightforward say to keep a few Linux machines on the same patch level? I'd need this separately for a few Ubuntu, and a few CentOS 7 (actually Oracle Linux 7, but close enough as CentOS is probably more familiar to others), machines.

EDIT: Just to clarify, different distros don't have to be "on the same patch level", so I just need to keep e.g. the Ubuntu 16.xx machines at the same patch level, the Ubuntu 18.xx machines at the same patch level, the Oracle Linux 7.x machines at the same patch level etc.

What I mean is this. I have a CentOS 7 machine A that I update with "sudo yum update". It has the default repositories plus some additional third-party repositories. Then one month later I want to update another CentOS 7 machine, but not to the newest packages, but to the same versions as on machine A.

If there are disparencies with what repositories and packages are installed (like machine A has a [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/) and [Jenkins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_%28software%29) repository and package installed, while B doesn't have them, or vice versa), those wouldn't count but would be updated to the newest version available on either machine. So only those packages would be "version-restricted" that exist on both machines.

I know that at least in CentOS ([YUM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellowdog_Updater,_Modified)) you can update a package to a certain version instead of the newest one, and I presume that is possible also with [APT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APT_(software)) on Ubuntu. The question is if there is a tool for both Ubuntu and CentOS that would use the output (what packages are installed and what versions they are) from the first machine as input on the second machines, to which version to update it, *if* that package (and repository) is installed there too. And then the rest would be updated to whatever is the newest version.

I've tried to google for this earlier, and I see mainly two suggestions:

1. Set up local repositories. I have actually done that, but it just seems too massive and heavy-handed, just so that I can keep a few machines at the same patch level. Makes more sense if there are dozens or hundreds of machines to update and keep at the same patch level (at that point also automating it all with [Ansible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansible_(software)) or something).
2. Use some installation media CD that has a certain patch level, and install the updates from there. I am not quite sure how this works, but mainly, don't those media CDs include only the official distribution  repositories? How about the third-party repositories that have been added later on the machines, like Jenkins, [GitLab CI](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/), Chrome, epel and what have you?

Comment: Have a look at [Chef](https://www.chef.io/), it's intended to keep a bunch of machines in the same patch state. But no, it's not "simple". And if you need both Ubuntu and CentOS, there probably isn't a simpler solution.

Comment: I just edited the original question to clarify that I don't need to keep e.g. Ubuntu and Centos machines at the "same patch level", but e.g. all the Ubuntu 16.x machines at the same, Centos 7.x machines at the same etc. So basically, I want to restrict the updates to certain date(s), like "install the same versions on these machines that I installed on those other machines a month ago". Naturally for some package this might be a different version between different distros, and that is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an easier way to do this using package lock files.
[yum-versionlock](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/yum-versionlock.1.html) should allow you to create a reference lock file on machine A, which you could then copy to other centOS 7 machines either manually or using Ansible.

If you only care about a few packages then it's easier to manage them using Ansible. If you really need ALL packages kept at exactly the same versions across machines then yum-versionlock is the way to go. You could still use Ansible to copy across the lock file from machine A.

Install yum-versionlock

```
[centos@ec2]$ sudo yum -y install yum-versionlock
```

Then add all packages with `*` or a specific package like `httpd`

```
[centos@ec2]$ sudo versionlock add *
```

You should see these packages in the `versionlock.list` file as specified in `versionlock.conf`. By default these files are in `/etc/yum/pluginconfg.d/`

```
[centos@ec2]$ cat /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/versionlock.conf
[main]
enabled = 1
locklist = /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/versionlock.list
#  Show a hint when any locked packages have updates available
show_hint = 1
#  Uncomment this to lock out "upgrade via. obsoletes" etc. (slower)
# follow_obsoletes = 1

[centos@ec2]$ cat /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/versionlock.list
# Added locks on Mon Jun 22 20:05:02 2020
0:libverto-libevent-0.2.5-4.el7.*
0:nss-sysinit-3.44.0-7.el7_7.*
10:qemu-guest-agent-2.12.0-3.el7.*
1:wpa_supplicant-2.6-12.el7.*
2:shadow-utils-4.6-5.el7.*
0:libgcrypt-1.5.3-14.el7.*
0:rsyslog-8.24.0-41.el7_7.2.*
0:gettext-libs-0.19.8.1-2.el7.*
...
```

Then copy `versionlock.list` to another machine and run `sudo yum install -y` or `sudo yum update -y`and it will install or update all packages to the versions in the lock file. If you just run update it should only update what you already have to what the lock file allows (but I haven't tried this).

For other OSes there are similar tools, as [explained here for apt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120021/what-is-the-equivalent-to-yum-versionlock-for-ubuntu), but I don't know of a tool that locks packages across different package managers.

Again if you only care about some packages you could use Ansible's [package module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/package_module.html) to do this but you might find some use cases you'll have to use yum and other package manager specific modules. This can get messy but will be worthwhile.

If you absolutely need a single tool then you could feasibly use Ansible to create the package lock files from jinja2 templates across the different package managers you need to support and then copy them to your machines. This would take longer to setup and be error prone but would allow you to maintain a single list of packages to install.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into those tools. By the sound of it, they might be what I was looking for.
About this: "...but I don't know of a tool that locks packages across different package managers."
Sorry I wasn't clearer in my original message, but there is no need to be "version-locked" across different distros or distro versions. Mainly just "date-locked", that I will install the same versions of packages that I installed on another patch of machines a month earlier. If that means that Centos 7 and Ubuntu 16 will get a different version of the same package, that is fine for me.